# Two calls to layerClass and initWithCoder, why?

Tags: objective-c, initialization, layer

2011-04-06 19:30:39.268 GLFun[531:707] Called!
2011-04-06 19:30:39.276 GLFun[531:707] 0x12e0e0
2011-04-06 19:30:39.279 GLFun[531:707] CAEAGLLayer
2011-04-06 19:30:39.482 GLFun[531:707] Called!
2011-04-06 19:30:39.485 GLFun[531:707] 0x1322c0
2011-04-06 19:30:39.488 GLFun[531:707] CAEAGLLayer

Well, I've been studying the workings of a typical OpenGL ES example found in the XCode template library. I was wondering when does the layerClass get invoked (before or after the initWithCoder method). It turns out it's after the initWithCoder (Called! in the log). But I have something interesting happening, at least to me. I get a redundant call to init and layerClass all over again exactly 16864 bytes further in memory from the last ( 0x12e0e0 -> 0x1322c0).

Could anybody clarify why there is a double call or why is there a redundant object at 0x1322c0 of the same class (EAGLView) which invokes the initWithCoder and layerClass all over again? There have been no changes to the OpenGL ES template, only the addition of NSLog for following what's happening.

Comment: Unable to reproduce in the iPhone Simulator running iOS 4.3. Where are you seeing this? What are the backtraces for each of those calls to `+layerClass`?

Comment: It seems that you are right, I just created another OGLES project and it calls it just once. Same setup, this is very interesting... And I tried following the trail but after the second init it just purges all data and jumps... Not important anymore, thanks for the assist... It seems a small hiccup. Thanks!